# iPhone 13 Pro Restarts Unexpectedly with Panic Log

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, kernel-panic, restart

The iOS and all Apps are updated to newest; it will restart unexpectedly without regular.

[image]
[image]

The last reboot time is *2023-01-03*.

Some panic log:

```
{"bug_type":"210","timestamp":"2023-01-03 14:17:11.00 +0800","os_version":"iPhone OS 16.2 (20C65)","roots_installed":0,"incident_id":"B206022B-***-E2B1E48A06D3"}
{
  "build" : "iPhone OS 16.2 (20C65)",
  "product" : "iPhone14,2",
  "socId" : "0x00008110",
  "kernel" : "Darwin Kernel Version 22.2.0: Mon Nov 28 20:10:56 PST 2022; root:xnu-8792.62.2~1\/RELEASE_ARM64_T8110",
  "incident" : "B206022B-***-E2B1E48A06D3",
  "crashReporterKey" : "4e7f5afec7ca6728040678d24728f04c5633ad44",
  "date" : "2023-01-03 14:17:11.96 +0800",
  "panicString" : "panic(cpu 3 caller 0xfffffff01a5ce78c): Kernel data abort. at pc 0xfffffff019fb3bb0, lr 0xf5bbc8f019f9e4bc (saved state: 0xffffffe8fffcfa80)
      x0:  0xfffffff1b3c6a440 x1:  0xffffffe3e6a949c0  x2:  0x00000000000030c7  x3:  0x000000000000000c
      x4:  0xffffffefffe9b8d8 x5:  0x00000009b2e00000  x6:  0x0000000000000000  x7:  0x0000000000000001
      x8:  0x0000000000000000 x9:  0xfffffff1b3150000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0xffffffe000000000
      x12: 0x0000000000000030 x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0xfffffff1b3150000  x15: 0x00000000000030c7
      x16: 0x000000020e400000 x17: 0x000000000000001b  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0xfffffff1b3c6a440
      x20: 0xffffffe0e6942c00 x21: 0xfffffff1b30eac30  x22: 0xfffffff01c4eb000  x23: 0xfffffff019942000
      x24: 0xfffffff1b2ed0000 x25: 0x000000000001ac3c  x26: 0xffffffe000000000  x27: 0xfffffff01c4cbe00
      x28: 0xffffffe3e6a94de8 fp:  0xffffffe8fffcfe30  lr:  0xf5bbc8f019f9e4bc  sp:  0xffffffe8fffcfdd0
      pc:  0xfffffff019fb3bb0 cpsr: 0x00401208         esr: 0x96000005          far: 0x0000000000000028

Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0xff
OS release type: User
OS version: 20C65
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 22.2.0: Mon Nov 28 20:10:56 PST 2022; root:xnu-8792.62.2~1\/RELEASE_ARM64_T8110
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: F2FE6DA3A669DFCDA093D36C045A403E
Kernel UUID: 44C9736D-8FB6-39CB-BC78-18AE47269CD5
Boot session UUID: B206022B-***-E2B1E48A06D3
iBoot version: iBoot-8419.60.44
secure boot?: YES
roots installed: 0
Paniclog version: 14
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000012138000
KernelCache base:  0xfffffff01913c000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000012dbc000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffff019dc0000
Kernel text exec slide: 0x0000000012e78000
Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffff019e7c000
mach_absolute_time: 0x11b48c24fb6
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x63b23259 0x0001f199
  Sleep   : 0x63b3c608 0x00006fdb
  Wake    : 0x63b3c65e 0x0009b7b3
  Calendar: 0x63b3c84e 0x0008880d

Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xffffffe0003e4000 - 0xffffffe6003e4000
  . VM    : 0xffffffe0003e4000 - 0xffffffe0e6a48000
  . RO    : 0xffffffe0e6a48000 - 0xffffffe133714000
  . GEN0  : 0xffffffe133714000 - 0xffffffe219d78000
  . GEN1  : 0xffffffe219d78000 - 0xffffffe3003dc000
  . GEN2  : 0xffffffe3003dc000 - 0xffffffe3e6a44000
  . GEN3  : 0xffffffe3e6a44000 - 0xffffffe4cd0ac000
  . DATA  : 0xffffffe4cd0ac000 - 0xffffffe6003e4000
  Metadata: 0xffffffe8fc2cc000 - 0xffffffe8fdacc000
  Bitmaps : 0xffffffe8fdacc000 - 0xffffffe8ffb34000

CORE 0 recently retired instr at 0xfffffff019ffed34
CORE 1 recently retired instr at 0xfffffff019ffed34
CORE 2 recently retired instr at 0xfffffff019ffed34
CORE 3 recently retired instr at 0xfffffff019ffd850
CORE 4 recently retired instr at 0xfffffff019ffed34
CORE 5 recently retired instr at 0xfffffff019ffed34
TPIDRx_ELy = {1: 0xffffffe3e6a949c0  0: 0x0000000000000003  0ro: 0x0000000000000000 }
CORE 0: PC=0xfffffff019ef4c40, LR=0xfffffff019ef4c3c, FP=0xffffffea6256ff00
CORE 1: PC=0x0000000193141f54, LR=0x00000001931423c8, FP=0x000000016fe45650
CORE 2: PC=0xfffffff019ef4c3c, LR=0xfffffff019ef4c3c, FP=0xffffffe8ffe0ff00
CORE 3 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE 4: PC=0xfffffff019ef4c40, LR=0xfffffff019ef4c3c, FP=0xffffffe8ffe1bf00
CORE 5: PC=0xfffffff019ef4c40, LR=0xfffffff019ef4c3c, FP=0xffffffea62563f00
ECC Corrections:37
Compressor Info: 97% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 39% of segments limit (OK) with 2 swapfiles and OK swap space
Panicked task 0xffffffe300345238: 0 pages, 483 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe3e6a949c0, backtrace: 0xffffffe8fffcf1c0, tid: 101
          lr: 0xfffffff019ec2160  fp: 0xffffffe8fffcf200
          lr: 0xfffffff019ec1f34  fp: 0xffffffe8fffcf270
          lr: 0xfffffff01a004a18  fp: 0xffffffe8fffcf290
          lr: 0xfffffff019ff7810  fp: 0xffffffe8fffcf300
          lr: 0xfffffff019ff60fc  fp: 0xffffffe8fffcf3c0
          lr: 0xfffffff019e836b4  fp: 0xffffffe8fffcf3d0
          lr: 0xfffffff019ec1948  fp: 0xffffffe8fffcf780
          lr: 0xfffffff01a5c589c  fp: 0xffffffe8fffcf7a0
          lr: 0xfffffff01a5ce78c  fp: 0xffffffe8fffcf920
          lr: 0xfffffff019ff7704  fp: 0xffffffe8fffcf9a0
          lr: 0xfffffff019ff648c  fp: 0xffffffe8fffcfa60
          lr: 0xfffffff019e836b4  fp: 0xffffffe8fffcfa70
          lr: 0xfffffff019f9e4bc  fp: 0xffffffe8fffcfe30
          lr: 0xfffffff019f9e4bc  fp: 0xffffffe8fffcfef0
          lr: 0xfffffff019f9f520  fp: 0xffffffe8fffcff20
          lr: 0xfffffff019e88a98  fp: 0x0000000000000000

last started kext at 404198392: com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   1110.14 (addr 0xfffffff019733840, size 111770)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleIDAMInterface 1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEthernetDevice 7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDeviceNCM  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDeviceMux  1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAccessoryPortUSB  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMike   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AOPTouchKext   311
com.apple.driver.AppleProxDriver    19
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedLightSensor   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleALSColorSensor    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPAD5860 600.99
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPHaptics    600.99
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPVoiceTrigger   200.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHapticsSupportNVM 7.20
com.apple.driver.AppleBasebandPCIMAVPDP 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCWirelessCharger    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManagerEmbedded   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartIO2  1
com.apple.driver.AppleCS42L77Audio  600.99
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedTouchEEPROM   1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMP   1
com.apple.driver.AppleGenericMultitouch 22
com.apple.driver.AppleHapticsSupportLEAP    7.20
com.apple.driver.ApplePMPFirmware   1
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.filesystems.tmpfs 1
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioResourceManager  600.99
com.apple.filesystems.lifs  1
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  2142.62.1
com.apple.IOTextEncryptionFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  627.40.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothModule   1
com.apple.driver.AppleIDV   5.207
com.apple.driver.AppleAVD   617.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH14P-
```

What's the problem with my phone? And how could I fix it?

Comment: A kernel panic on a device like this is typically hardware.  Start by wiping your phone completely.  Start clean.  F the problem persists, your phone needs service.